# php sum values based on same same ids in an array

Tags: php

I want to sum input['amount'] in given array only if input['ids'] are same. Please tell any best solution. Thanks

```
    $input = [
        'ids' => [1, 2, 3, 1],
        'amount' => [50, 100, null, 100]
    ];

    $result = [];

    foreach ($input['ids'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br>';

        if($key == $key) {
            $result['amount'] += $input['amount'][$key];
        }

    }

    // I want this result form input array. thanks
    $result = [
        'ids' => [1, 2, 3],
        'amount' => [150, 100, null]
    ];
```

Comment: Do the summing in an associative array that uses the ids as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array to hold the sums.

```
$sums = [];
foreach ($input['ids'] AS $index => $id) { // loop over the IDs
    if ($input['amount'][$index] !== null) { // check if the corresponding amount is not null 
        $sums[$id] += $input['amount'][$index]; // Add it to the associative array that's keyed by ID
    }
}
$result = [];
$result['ids'] = array_unique($input['ids']); // find all the different IDs
$result['amount'] = array_map(function($id) use($sums) {
    return $sums[$id] ?? null; // for each ID, return the sum, or null if all the corresponding amounts were null
}, $result['ids']);
```

Comment: its nice & good for us if you will explain it also with comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// new array, ids => amount
$ids = array_unique($input['ids']);

// intialise to 0 
foreach($ids as $id) {
  $tempMap[$id] = 0;
}

// sum
foreach(array_values($input['amount']) as $i => $amount) {    
  if (is_null($amount)) {
    $tempMap[ $input['ids'][$i] ] = $amount;  
  } else {
    $tempMap[ $input['ids'][$i] ] += $amount;
  }  
}

$result['ids'] = array_keys($tempMap);
$result['amount']  = array_values($tempMap);
```